# Linq code doesn't return correct record

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table named `dbo.EmployeeType` with three records:

```
PK_EmployeetypeID    EmployeeTypeName 
1                    Project Manager 
2                    Business Analyst 
3                    Developer
```

I have this piece of Linq code:

```
public static string GetTypeByID(int id)
{
    using (ProjectTrackingEntities1 db = new ProjectTrackingEntities1())
    {
        var type = db.EmployeeTypes.Select(o => new LOOKUPEmployeeType
        {
            PK_EmployeeTypeID = id,
            EmployeeTypeName = o.EmployeeTypeName
        });

        return type.FirstOrDefault().EmployeeTypeName;
    }
}
```

No matter what id I send to it, it returns `Project Manager`, and I'm confused as to why.

Comment: set a breakpoint on `type = ...` and inspect it. You have no WHERE in there so you get all - and Select just makes LOOKUPEmployeeTypes out of all of them.  FirstOrDefault returns the first which is always the ProjManager

Comment: Code always returns value of "first" (whatever DB consider to be "first" in no particular order) record... Can you please clarify what do you expect this code to do? (or someone who upvoted post could have done the same).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to apply a filter, otherwise you're just returning the first record and hard coding the ID. Try this:

```
public static string GetTypeByID(int id)
{
    using (ProjectTrackingEntities1 db = new ProjectTrackingEntities1())
    {
        //Here we apply a filter, the lambda here is what creates the WHERE clause
        var type = db.EmployeeTypes
            .FirstOrDefault(et => et.PK_EmployeeTypeID == id);

        if(type != null)
        {
            return type.EmployeeTypeName;
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Note that using `FirstOrDefault` means if there are no matches, or multiple matches, `type` will be `null` and you will get an empty string returned.

Comment: ahh, that makes sense and is a LOT cleaner than what I was trying to do

Comment: You may wish to do something different than return an empty string if no record is found of course.

Comment: yeah, it's a required field in the database so in theory that piece should never get called

Comment: It's more what to do if an invalid `id` is passed in, that would be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Set a breakpoint on `type = ...` and inspect it. You have no `Where` in there so you get all - and `Select` just makes `LOOKUPEmployeeTypes` out of all of them.

`FirstOrDefault` then returns the first of those 3 which is always the ProjManager

Fix:

```
var type = db
    .EmployeeTypes
    .Where( o => o.Id == id)
    .Select(o => new LOOKUPEmployeeType
{
    PK_EmployeeTypeID = id,
    EmployeeTypeName = o.EmployeeTypeName
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you only return the first value. You need to tell EF which value you need to return.

Let us assume you need the value with Id=2. Instead of `Select()`, use `Single(x => x.Id == 2)` or `First(x => x.Id == 2)`.